# R Programming - Data Cleaning - DateTime

Tags: r, datetime, data-cleaning

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am currently working with a large dataset that has Date/Time variable and a numeric variable that quantifies the time spent in physical activity of a certain intensity. The dataset is in the form:

[image: data_raw]

```
data_raw <- structure(list(`Bout Start` = c("2/8/2017 9:01:00 AM", "2/8/2017 9:23:00 AM", "2/8/2017 9:42:00 AM", "2/8/2017 11:49:00 AM", "2/8/2017 1:39:00 PM"), `Bout End` = c("2/8/2017 9:12:00 AM", "2/8/2017 9:38:00 AM", "2/8/2017 9:52:00 AM", "2/8/2017 12:05:00 PM", "2/8/2017 1:58:00 PM"),`Time in Bout` = c(11, 15, 10, 16, 19)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I require my dataset in the form:

[image: data_processed]

```
data_processed <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(Date5306 = 17205, Date5307 = 17205, Date5308 = 17205, Date5309 = 17205, Date5310 = 17205), class = "Date"), Hour = structure(c(28800, 32400, 36000, 39600, 43200), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), `Time in Bout (Hourly)` = c(0, 36, 0, 11, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Could someone please help me do this? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to convert your date-time strings in `data_raw` to actual date-time variables:

```r
data <- within(data_raw, {
  `Bout Start` <- as.POSIXct(`Bout Start`, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
  `Bout End`   <- as.POSIXct(`Bout End`,   format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
})
```

Now your data looks like this:

```
data
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   `Bout Start`        `Bout End`          `Time in Bout`
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>                       <dbl>
#> 1 2017-02-08 09:01:00 2017-02-08 09:12:00             11
#> 2 2017-02-08 09:23:00 2017-02-08 09:38:00             15
#> 3 2017-02-08 09:42:00 2017-02-08 09:52:00             10
#> 4 2017-02-08 11:49:00 2017-02-08 12:05:00             16
#> 5 2017-02-08 13:39:00 2017-02-08 13:58:00             19
```

We now need to create a vector of hours at which you want to check for bouts:

```
times <- seq(as.POSIXct("2017-02-08 08:00"), by = "hour", len = 7)
```

The tricky part is now just counting the minutes within each of these hours when there was a bout taking place:

```r
mins <- rowSums(sapply(seq(nrow(data)), function(i) {
   a <- data$`Bout End`[i] - times
   a <- ifelse(a > 0 & a < 60, a, 0)
   b <- data$`Bout Start`[i] - times
   b <- ifelse(b > 0 & b < 60, b, 0)
   (a - b) %% 60
}))
```

Finally, we create a data frame of the results:

```r
data.frame(Date = as.Date(head(times, -1)),
           Hour = strftime(head(times, -1), "%H:%M:%S"),
           `Time in bout` = head(mins, -1), check.names = FALSE)
#>         Date     Hour Time in bout
#> 1 2017-02-08 08:00:00            0
#> 2 2017-02-08 09:00:00           36
#> 3 2017-02-08 10:00:00            0
#> 4 2017-02-08 11:00:00           11
#> 5 2017-02-08 12:00:00            5
#> 6 2017-02-08 13:00:00           19
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A rather complex task, here is a `tidyverse` approach

- get the sequence of dates/hours to enable filling of missing data, `dd1`
- split hour-spanning times into their corresponding hour bin, `dd2`
- join `dd1` and `dd2`
- also, on the fly, convert strings to dates and hours/full hours

Note, it's a dynamic approach; starting and ending hours/dates show up once they appear in the raw data.

```
library(dplyr) # >= v1.1.0 for ".by" in full_join's summarize and consecutive_id
library(tidyr) # separate and replace_na
library(lubridate) # date functions

dd1 <- tibble(ID = seq(
         ymd_hms(format(first(mdy_hms(data_raw$`Bout Start`)),
         "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")), 
         ymd_hms(format(last(mdy_hms(data_raw$`Bout Start`)), 
         "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")), 3600))

dd1
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  ID                 
  <dttm>             
1 2017-02-08 09:00:00
2 2017-02-08 10:00:00
3 2017-02-08 11:00:00
4 2017-02-08 12:00:00
5 2017-02-08 13:00:00
```

```
dd2 <- data_raw %>% 
  mutate(`Bout Start` = mdy_hms(`Bout Start`), 
         `Bout End` = mdy_hms(`Bout End`), 
         is = format(`Bout Start`, "%H") != format(`Bout End`, "%H")) %>%
  uncount(is + 1) %>% 
  group_by(grp = consecutive_id(is)) %>% 
  mutate(`Bout Start` = if_else(is & row_number() == 2, 
     ymd_hms(format(first(`Bout End`), "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")), `Bout Start`), 
         `Bout End` = if_else(is & row_number() == 1, 
     ymd_hms(format(first(`Bout End`), "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")), `Bout End`), 
         `Time in Bout` = `Bout End` - `Bout Start`, 
         ID = ymd_hms(format(`Bout Start`, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")), is = NULL) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)

dd2
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  `Bout Start`        `Bout End`          `Time in Bout` ID                 
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>         <dttm>             
1 2017-02-08 09:01:00 2017-02-08 09:12:00 11 mins        2017-02-08 09:00:00
2 2017-02-08 09:23:00 2017-02-08 09:38:00 15 mins        2017-02-08 09:00:00
3 2017-02-08 09:42:00 2017-02-08 09:52:00 10 mins        2017-02-08 09:00:00
4 2017-02-08 11:49:00 2017-02-08 12:00:00 11 mins        2017-02-08 11:00:00
5 2017-02-08 12:00:00 2017-02-08 12:05:00  5 mins        2017-02-08 12:00:00
6 2017-02-08 13:39:00 2017-02-08 13:58:00 19 mins        2017-02-08 13:00:00
```

Joining `dd1` and `dd2`, also separating `Date` and `Hour` and replace `NA` from missing dates/hours with `0`.

```
full_join(dd1, dd2, multiple="all") %>% 
  mutate(`Time in Bout` = replace_na(`Time in Bout`, duration(0))) %>% 
  summarize(`Time in Bout (Hourly)` = sum(`Time in Bout`), .by = ID) %>% 
  separate(ID, c("Date", "Hour"), sep=" ")
Joining with `by = join_by(ID)`
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Date       Hour     `Time in Bout (Hourly)`
  <chr>      <chr>    <drtn>                 
1 2017-02-08 09:00:00 36 mins                
2 2017-02-08 10:00:00  0 mins                
3 2017-02-08 11:00:00 11 mins                
4 2017-02-08 12:00:00  5 mins                
5 2017-02-08 13:00:00 19 mins
```